# Make popup on load working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I'm trying to make a pop up right away when page is loading , but all the browsers are blocking it and don't let the pop up works , this is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function codeAddress() {
javascript:void window.open('http://google.com','1411977082597','width=750,height=550,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;
}

window.onload = codeAddress;
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a solution for that ?

Comment: its working see here  http://jsfiddle.net/2wzmtv1v/

Answer (score 1):

do not need following code

```
javascript:void
```

this code use when write javascript on html tags

```
function codeAddress() {
     window.open('http://google.com','1411977082597','width=750,height=550,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');
}
```

Check your browser javascript enable.

Check your browser allow popup.

**Allow popup to work using Javascript is impossible.**

Comment: the popup is working but I need to to make my browser allow the popup to make it work , I mean this is not working by default..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by calling your method in jquery document.ready method. like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      codeAddress();
})
```